# Using R to query geodatabase to use in bioconductor

Tags: r, geolocation, bioconductor

I am trying to import geodatabase GSE files into R and I do not know how to get them in a format that can be analyzed by bioconductor software can you tell me how to do so?

Comment: What is a geodatabase GSE file? Give us a clue here.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the [GEOquery](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/html/GEOquery.html) package? Be sure to read the [vignette](http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/vignettes/GEOquery/inst/doc/GEOquery.pdf)